# Firebase Database POJO deserialisation ignore missing properties

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a POJO in my android code which has one property `fieldB` which is not always set in the database (especially for old data).

```
class POJO {
    String fieldA;
    String fieldB;

    public POJO() {}

    public String getFieldA(){
        return fieldA;
    }

    public String getFieldB(){
        return fieldB;
    }
}
```

When deserialising using `getValue(POJO.class)`, Firebase returns `null` because it cannot find `fieldB` in the DataSnapshot. How do I tell it to ignore missing properties or better yet, set a default value in the missing case.

Comment: Did you try the annotation `@Exclude`?

Comment: Firebase SDKs version 9.x and higher will by default ignore missing properties. Can you show the JSON you're trying to read with this POJO, and the code that does the reading?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the json should be `"key":{"fieldA": "valueA"}`